# Can't get connected mode to work in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, sonarlint

I'm struggling to get the connected mode to connect to my local instance of SonarQube.

I'm suspecting it has something to do with the way my system is set up.

I'm using a Mac (OS X 10.11.x) and I have PHP and Apache set up according to [this tutorial](http://alanthing.com/blog/2014/12/22/os-x-1010-yosemite-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew/). I think perhaps there is an issue with a firewall rule or something.

When I connect to http://localhost:9000/api/system/status with a browser, there is no problem. telnet localhost 9000 works fine too.

But when I enter credentials and create a configuration in SonarLint, I always get:

> error testing connection: Fail to request http://localhost:9000/api/system/status

Anybody have a clue?

Answer (score 2):

It is also worth to check [SonarLint issue tracker](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel). Issue looks related rather to the plugin than PhpStorm itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Phpstorm log folder `~/Library/Logs/PhpStormVERSION/FILE.log` (FILE - some log file for phpstorm, in Intellij it's idea.log)
I see the tutorial you followed enabled SSL and I guess that should be because of a certificate.